# Building Dynamic Queries Using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, datatable

my first post and hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I'm trying to create dynamic linq queries to transform data tables in my application. This is an example of a hard coded Linq query I'm using.

```
transformedData = (from a in bankedSourceData.Datatable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                    where bankedCompareData.Datatable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Any(r => Equals(r["DummyColumn"], a["DummyColumn"]))
                     select a).CopyToDataTable();
```

I'm trying to find rows in one table where the data exists in another table. I have third table which is dictating what to match on in the Linq query. The problem I have is there could be times when I need to add another condition to the where clause to match on a second or more columns.

Is there a way to turn a string into a Lambda or any other alternative for this?

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: you should refer this https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deveshomar/dynamic-linq-library-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: You can use [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) to create strongly typed queries dynamically, or you can go all the way to [Dynamic LINQ](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core) that converts a simplified string query language into queries. You could also use lambda syntax and daisy-chain the `Where` method calls. Note that `AsEnumerable()` can replace `Rows.Cast<DataRow>()`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments; I’ve never experimented enough with linq to reach its full potential and I had no idea you could daisy chain the where methods. Taking a look at libqkit though seems like a solid answer.

Comment: If you're looking to get ultimate control over the process you can also check out `LINQ Expression Trees`: this is the technology that all other libraries will rely on so might be useful to get yourself familiar with it